Identifying feature without creating separate output
I am using ArcGIS Pro 3.2.
I hoping to use the Identity tool to cookie cutter a buffer(layer B) into a polygon (layer A) without creating a separate output feature class. Currently I am using the identity tool like:
arcpy.analysis.Identity(
in_features=layer A,
identity_features=layer B,
out_feature_class=layer C)

deleting what's currently in layer A then appending layer C to layer A.
This works in a single work flow but I am trying to automate the process. During automation I will not be able to specify which data gets deleted and possibly delete all data in layer A if a selection is not made correctly.

The Identity (Analysis) tool:

Computes a geometric intersection of the input features and identity
features. The input features or portions thereof that overlap identity
features will get the attributes of those identity features.

Its Usage is:
arcpy.analysis.Identity(in_features, identity_features, out_feature_class, {join_attributes}, {cluster_tolerance}, {relationship})

where the out_feature_class parameter is mandatory and represents:

The feature class that will be created and to which the results will
be written.

Since it always creates an output feature class you will not be able to:

use the Identity tool to cookie cutter a buffer(layer B) into a
polygon (layer A) without creating a separate output feature class.

I am not clear on exactly what you are trying to do but ArcPy geometries can be used to intersect geometries in memory.  However, at some point I think you will need to output your result as a feature in a feature class so you may find it easiest to just accept that Identity creates output features and use a simpler workflow with that as a constraint.

Consider using a Union tool instead. It's output creates a useful -1 value in the ID column when for say a polygon does not overlap. You can use that to identify overlaps vs. non-overlaps in the data. This could all be easily automated with selections in model builder and you do something with the selection (e.g. delete out the intersection or feed a subset into further processing).
